# Unicode version supported by Java 6

Tags: unicode, java-6

Anyone know the answer?  According to http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/basic/intl/faq.jsp, it's 4.0 for 5.  Has it been upgraded in 6?  Link to reference would be much appreciated as well.

Comment: In later versions of Java, the [java.lang.Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class doc mentions the version of Unicode supported. Example in Java 8 Update 74: `Character information is based on the Unicode Standard, version 6.2.0.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the ICU (International Components for Unicode), [Java 6 is Unicode 4](http://site.icu-project.org/home/why-use-icu4j)

Comment: Its seems even not to be Unicode 4.1. With JDK 1.6.0_22 I get for the character '\u0237' (LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS J) that it is unassigned. But according to http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/237/index.htm it is assigned.

Answer (score 5):

I needed to know the [Unicode version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Versions) supported by a particular Java version for several times, why not answer one of these questions to make it easier for the next time. So, a `7 YEARS LATER` answer:

From [Unicode Versions Supported in Java-History](http://www.herongyang.com/Unicode/Java-Unicode-Version-Supported-in-Java-History.html), last updated in 2012:

```
Java version   Release date         Unicode version

JDK 1.0        January 23, 1996     Unicode 1.1.5
JDK 1.1        February 19, 1997    Unicode 2.0
JDK 1.1.7      September 12, 1997   Unicode 2.1
J2SE 1.2       December 8, 1998     Unicode 2.1
J2SE 1.3       May 8, 2000          Unicode 2.1
J2SE 1.4       February 6, 2002     Unicode 3.0
J2SE 5.0       September 30, 2004   Unicode 4.0
Java SE 6      December 11, 2006    Unicode 4.0
Java SE 7      July 28, 2011        Unicode 6.0
```

## JEPs

The [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project publishes a JEP document for each version incrementing Unicode.

- [*JEP 128: Unicode BCP 47 Locale Matching*](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/128) in Java SE 8.
- [*JEP 133*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/133) adds support for Unicode 6.2 in [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8).
  See also: [Internationalization Enhancements in JDK 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/enhancements.8.html).
- [*JEP 227*](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/227) for adding [Unicode 7](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode7.0.0/) support in Java SE 9.
  [*JEP 267*](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/267) adds support for Unicode 8 in Java SE 9 as well.
- [*JEP 314: Additional Unicode Language-Tag Extensions*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/314) in Java SE 10. (Tags for currency type, the first day of the week, region override and time zone will now be supported.)
- [*JEP 327*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/327) adds [Unicode 10](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode10.0.0/) support in Java SE 11.
- [*Release Note: Support for Unicode 11*](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8213991) explains support for Unicode 11 in Java 12.

Listing.

```
Java version   Release date         Unicode version

Java SE  8     2014-03              Unicode  6.2.0
Java SE  9     2017-09              Unicode  7.0 
                                          &  8.0
Java SE 11     2018-09              Unicode 10.0
Java SE 12     2019-03              Unicode 11.0
Java SE 13.0.2                      Unicode 12.1
```

See Java 13.0.2 [Release Notes](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/13all-relnotes.html).

Answer (score 2):

Unicode 5.1 is on the [planned features list](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/features/#f497) for Java in JDK 7. In Java 6 it remains Unicode 4.0.

Answer (score -2):

IDNA standard, see [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/i18n_enhance/).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand...  Are you saying that the version supported is the version where the IDNA standard was added?