# Why does Java not recognize these white spaces?

Tags: java, character-encoding

There are [25 types of white spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode). `Character.isWhitespace(char)` in the code below shows that four of the 25 types are not considered as white space in Java. Why ?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String...args){
        char [] whiteSpaces = {'\u0085', '\u00A0', '\u2007', '\u202F'};
        for(char space : whiteSpaces){
            //All spaces are not white spaces in Java.
            System.out.println("[" + space + "] is a white space in Java:" + Character.isWhitespace(space));
        }
    }
}
```

Refer -https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(char)

Comment: Why the downvote ? Can this question be improved or do I need to research more before I post this question ? Please advise. I'll gladly delete this question if it already exists or if I can obtain the answer myself.

Comment: @Andreas - ok. I did not understand the implicit part. I wonder if it should be mentioned explicitly in the docs. Should I vote to close my own question ?

Comment: So should the javadoc also explicitly mention that e.g. `'A'` is not a "white space according to Java"? Of course not, so why should it mention `'\u0085'`? The javadoc gives a perfect definition of a Java white space, you just have to read it.

Comment: @Andreas - Yes. But, the chart I shared in the question mentions things which are generally considered as white space. Obviously, without even reading that chart, I know that 'A' could not be in the chart. I wonder what that chart means. Are languages free to consider only part of the chart as white space ?

Comment: *"**generally** considered as white space"* --- The [`Character.isWhitespace(char ch)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace-char-) has never claimed to use a "general" definition of white space. It **explicitly** says *"Determines if the specified character is white space **according to Java**"*.

Comment: @Andreas - ok. Btw, this is the chart I mentioned in the question https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode. So, I guess that languages are free to define white space. It does not have to be the same for every language. Is that correct ?

Comment: Languages claiming to use the Unicode definition of whitespace must follow that standard. The method you're calling *(I'll say it yet again)* **explicitly** specifies that it follows another definition. As such, *that specific method* can do whatever it wants to, and it has adequately documented what it is doing, so everybody (who actually **reads** the documentation) will know what it is.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I did not read the documentation carefully.

Comment: I'm upvoting this question and I especially find some of the "RTFM" like comments here very problematic. I'm working on a DSL that interops between many different languages., and I need the whitespace recognition to behave similarly between them. In particular, Java is one of the only few languages that deviates from unicode's standard of what is considered a whitespace and I need to understand the "why" to ensure I carve out an appropriate special casing just for this language. Just because the documentation explicitly said something doesn't mean you can't ask the reasoning behind it.

Comment: @TtT23 - Thanks. I agree with this - "Just because the documentation explicitly said something doesn't mean you can't ask the reasoning behind it." I read my question again and that is exactly what I was doing. Many of these experts on SO are quite arrogant and don't understand what it is like to be a beginner or misunderstand something. Its easy to be a keyboard warrior. Anyway, I still thank people for the answers, but I hope I don't have to work with such people if this is how they react to every question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why?  Because that is how that method is specified.  The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(char)) for `isWhiteSpace` lists the codes that it matches.  The 4 that you identified are not in the list.

**We can't tell you why it was defined that way.**  However, one implication of what the javadoc says is that `'\u00A0'`, `'\u2007'` and `'\u202F'` are excluded because they are non-breaking whitespace characters.

`'\u0085'` or `NEL` is an interesting case.  According to the Unicode code tables (see [here](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category) for an unofficial summary) it is NOT a member of the general categories SPACE_SEPARATOR, LINE_SEPARATOR or PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR.  (It shows up in the CONTROL category.)

If you want a method that recognises all Unicode white space characters (i.e. characters in SPACE_SEPARATOR, LINE_SEPARATOR or PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR), you should use `isSpaceChar` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isSpaceChar(char))) instead of `isWhiteSpace`.

Note that the Unicode spec is not a constant thing.  The categorization of the codes, and indeed the definition of "white space" has evolved over time.  Each [Java version implements a specific version of the Unicode spec](https://stackoverflow.com/q/793402/642706) that was current at the time it was released.  For example:

- Java 8 implements Unicode 6.2
- Java 11 implements Unicode 10.0.0
- Java 13 implements Unicode 12.1

The details are in the javadoc for the `Character` class for each Java version.  Note that a given Java release is NOT patched to track subsequent Unicode releases.

---

The bottom line is that "white space" is a rather slippery concept.  If you want a method that implements a specific meaning, you may need to implement it yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Btw, I tried isSpaceChar(int codePoint) and also isSpaceChar(char) for {'\n', '\u2001', '\u2007'}. Both of those methods, don't return true for all these 3 inputs.

Comment: Yes.  If you look at the categories I linked to, you will understand why they didn't.

Answer (score 3):

If you **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`Character.isWhitespace(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace-char-), it says:

> Determines if the specified character is white space according to Java. A character is a Java whitespace character **if and only if** it satisfies one of the following criteria:
>
> - It is a Unicode space character ([`SPACE_SEPARATOR`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/list.htm), [`LINE_SEPARATOR`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zl/list.htm), or [`PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zp/list.htm)) **but is not also a *non-breaking space* ([`'\u00A0'`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00A0/index.htm), [`'\u2007'`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2007/index.htm), [`'\u202F'`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202F/index.htm))**.
> - It is `'\t'`, `U+0009 HORIZONTAL TABULATION`.
> - It is `'\n'`, `U+000A LINE FEED`.
> - It is `'\u000B'`, `U+000B VERTICAL TABULATION`.
> - It is `'\f'`, `U+000C FORM FEED`.
> - It is `'\r'`, `U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN`.
> - It is `'\u001C'`, `U+001C FILE SEPARATOR`.
> - It is `'\u001D'`, `U+001D GROUP SEPARATOR`.
> - It is `'\u001E'`, `U+001E RECORD SEPARATOR`.
> - It is `'\u001F'`, `U+001F UNIT SEPARATOR`.

3 of the 4 you listed are explicitly excluded because they are *non-breaking spaces*.

As for [`U+0085 NEXT LINE (NEL)`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0085/index.htm), it is not a Unicode space character, and it is not considered a whitespace character by Java, as you can well see in that javadoc.

Comment: Thanks. 3/4 of the types were mentioned in the Java doc itself, but '\u0085' was not mentioned. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(char)

Comment: @MasterJoe Isn't that what I just said in the answer? Why are you repeating it back to me?

Comment: Andreas, because of the last paragraph "...as you can well see in that javadoc". I thought you meant that it is explicitly mentioned in the Javadoc that '\u0085' is not recognized. So, I thought I missed it and tried to search for any mention of just 0085 in the doc.

Comment: @MasterJoe You can well see it in the javadoc, since the javadoc lists the characters that it considers a whitespace, and `'\u0085'` is **not listed**, so why would you expect the method to return true for that character? It **explicitly** says *"if and only if"*, so anything not mentioned is "explicitly" excluded.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't seem to expose the unicode whitespace list anywhere

In Java, isWhitespace is specifically defined as one of these:

- It is a Unicode space character (SPACE_SEPARATOR, LINE_SEPARATOR, or PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR) but is not also a non-breaking space ('\u00A0', '\u2007', '\u202F').
- It is '\t', U+0009 HORIZONTAL TABULATION.
- It is '\n', U+000A LINE FEED.
- It is '\u000B', U+000B VERTICAL TABULATION.
- It is '\f', U+000C FORM FEED.
- It is '\r', U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN.
- It is '\u001C', U+001C FILE SEPARATOR.
- It is '\u001D', U+001D GROUP SEPARATOR.
- It is '\u001E', U+001E RECORD SEPARATOR.
- It is '\u001F', U+001F UNIT SEPARATOR.

Java also makes unicode *spaces* available, but not unicode whitespaces, via  `Character.isSpaceChar()`. This is a slightly different list.

```
char [] whiteSpaces = {'\u0085', '\u00A0', '\u2007', '\u202F'};
        for(char space : whiteSpaces){
            //All spaces are not white spaces in Java.
            System.out.println("[" + space + "] is a white space in Java: " + Character.isWhitespace(space) + " Unicode: " + Character.isSpaceChar(space));
        }
```

Output:

```
[] is a white space in Java: false Unicode: false
[ ] is a white space in Java: false Unicode: true
[ ] is a white space in Java: false Unicode: true
[ ] is a white space in Java: false Unicode: true
```

If it's important for your application to match the unicode specs instead of the java specs, just define it yourself.